# Command " symfony new my_project " don't usable

Tags: symfony

Good morning,
after change my PC (windows 10 Pro), I have a few problems… to use symfony.

If I do `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project` all is good,

but if I do `symfony new my_project --full` , I obtain :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uh3f.jpg)

And C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar exists :

[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxDJS.jpg)

I don't undestand if you have an idea…
Thank you in advance.

Comment: please paste your error as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Error is clear, the composer can't find a stable version with your PHP version.

Answer (score -1):

Which Php version(s) do you have?
Try `symfony local:php:list` and `symfony php -v` commands please.

---

• You can force Php version 7.4.0 for example with this command: `echo 7.4.0 > .php-version` inside your project folder.

Comment: Hmmm.  This seems more like a question or suggestion than an actual answer.  Not a good thing to do on stackoverflow.

Comment: True, I know he is running php 5 by default so I am helping him to use composer with a newer stable Php version with that commands